# In SQL Server sp_cursorprepare/sp_cursorexecute run extremely slowly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm running an application (Pentaho user console with the Saiku Ad-hoc plugin) which creates a query and runs it using sp_cursorprepare & sp_cursorexecute standard stored procedures.

My model is mostly made up of tables joined utilising the traditional foreign to primary key method.  However in the middle I have a linking table that contains foreign keys of the tables connected to it (with some other data) but its primary key is never referenced.  I have a clustered index on this table which references each of these foreign keys in order of the quantity of records.  When run the procedure call will the non-clustered primary key index and takes 6 - 7 minutes to run.  If I run the query on it's own it again uses the non-clustered primary key index although it runs in 7 seconds!

Is there anything I could do to combat this behaviour?